# Disable Single Sign On (SSO) in Facebook IOS SDK

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

We've built an iOS app that uses the Facebook SDK. Unfortunately, our client has asked that we disable backgrounding in the app and this means that the Facebook single-sign on (SSO) scheme doesn't work for us (as our app now starts from scratch when it is launched after the login/authorisation in the Facebook app).

So the question is: can we disable SSO in the Facebook iOS SDK such that it behaves like it did in older SDK versions with the Facebook login/ authorization happening within an in-app web-view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Facebook.m file in FBconnect library and find:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
         delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate {
```

set:

```
   [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

And FBconnect will authorize only with inside popup...

Comment: Can we do the same thing in FacebookSDK 3.1 and IOS 6?

Comment: @Johnykutty I have tried to do it in Facebook SDK 3.1 but didn't found anything. We can do it FBConnect as kviksilver mention in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know you can disable sso or not but i have a trick to do this.(every time need credential for login on facebook).

write these line in appDelegate's d`idFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
NSString *domainStr=(NSString *)[cookie domain];
NSLog(@"%@",domainStr);
if([domainStr isEqualToString:@".facebook.com" ])
{
[cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];

Answer (score -1):

you can save the state of your app before calling the facebook authentification process. 
but if the FB app is on the phone of your user, the

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self]
```

will redirect you to it.

But if you only have basic needs, you could use the webview part of the FB SDK. Using:

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self]
```

will make FB SDK displays a webview which will take care of the authorization process.