# Avoid Single Sign-on for Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

We'd built an iPad app which is mostly played by children on there parents iPad. Now we would like to implement the ability to share a photo on Facebook. The only difficulty is that we don't want the children to automatically post the photo on their parents wall. Therefor the children has to be forced to login with their own account.

We can achieve as described here:
[Disable Single Sign On (SSO) in Facebook IOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435578/disable-single-sign-on-sso-in-facebook-ios-sdk)

Only Facebook seems to reject apps which are not using SSO as described here:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10856344/appcenter-rejection-due-to-sso

Are there any other ways of avoiding SSO? Or is Facebook only rejecting the app if it is in the App Center?

NOTE: It seems all the Facebook apps are added to the App Center?

Answer (score -2):

There is a bigger flaw in your application than just SSO. You're forgetting that Children are not allowed to have Facebook Accounts. The minimum age for Facebook registration is 13, so unless your app is targeted to teenagers and older, you should scrap Facebook integration altogether.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, we'd took that in account. The target group of the app is from 12 till 14. So +/- 50% of the users can have a Facebook account. Teenagers is indeed a better word for describing our audience :)